# format of writing .sql files

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

lets say I have some sql queries or PL/SQL blocks that are supposed to be executed on a Database, I wrote all the scripts in a .sql file and tried to execute it using sqlplus CMD, and I usually get strange output.
All the scripts don't get executed only first gets executed, and I think this is because of improper use `'/'` character. So the question is how should I format it so that even though I am writing more than one script in one `.sql` file. All the files should get executed successfully.

```
CREATE TYPE schema1.ATTRIBUTES AS OBJECT (
  object_name    VARCHAR2(100),
  object_value   VARCHAR2(100));

CREATE TYPE schema1.ATTRIBUTETABLE AS TABLE OF KPNCUST.ATTRIBUTES;

COMMIT;

/
```

when I am executing this script using sqlplus I am having type created with compilation errors, but while deploying using TOAD I am not getting any error.

Comment: please post your .sql file

Answer (score 3):

In your original code everything from the first `CREATE TYPE` to the final `/` is being interpreted as a single command, and taken as a whole everything after the first semicolon is invalid syntax for that first create. If you did `show errors` after your solitary `/` you'd see:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -------------------------------------------
5/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"
```

The SQL*Plus documentation [describes what `/` does](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm), and also says [how to run PL/SQL blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663). It may not be obvious in this case but your example code has two PL/SQL blocks:

> Stored procedures are PL/SQL functions, packages, or procedures. To create stored procedures, you use the following SQL CREATE commands:
>
> - ...
> - CREATE TYPE
>
> Entering any of these commands places you in PL/SQL mode, where you can enter your PL/SQL subprogram. For more information, see Running PL/SQL Blocks. When you are done typing your PL/SQL subprogram, enter a period (.) on a line by itself to terminate PL/SQL mode. To run the SQL command and create the stored procedure, you must enter RUN or slash (/). A semicolon (;) will not execute these CREATE commands.

So you need a slash after each of your create commands, and don't strictly need semicolons for these examples:

```
CREATE TYPE schema1.ATTRIBUTES AS OBJECT (
  object_name    VARCHAR2(100),
  object_value   VARCHAR2(100))
/

CREATE TYPE schema1.ATTRIBUTETABLE AS TABLE OF schema1.ATTRIBUTES
/

COMMIT;
```

If you have that in a script (with a valid schema name, or omitting that for your own schema) and run the script through SQL*Plus you'll see:

```
SQL> @your_script.sql

Type created.


Type created.


Commit complete.
```

And you can check both were created:

```
SQL> select object_type, object_name, status from user_objects where object_name like 'ATTR%';

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME                    STATUS
------------------- ------------------------------ -------
TYPE                ATTRIBUTES                     VALID
TYPE                ATTRIBUTETABLE                 VALID
```

Your commit needs either a semicolon or a slash, but not both - it will commit twice if you do, which is just extra overhead. You don't really need to commit at all though, as DDL implicitly commits anyway.

So if you have a PL/SQL block or anything that SQL*Plus views as a stored procedure you have to submit it with a slash. For everything else you can use a semicolon (which you can even change with `set sqlterminator`) *or* a slash, but not both as that will execute it twice.

You may prefer to consistently use slashes even for plain SQL, or for all DDL. But remember the slash needs to be the first character on a new line, whereas the semicolon can immediately follow the actual command. It's really as matter of style and consistency unless you have coding standards you need to follow - either works, so use whichever makes more sense or is more readable to you.

Comment: are you sure that `/` will just execute the first statement and then move to the next one, and it will not execute the command in the SQL buffer again in any case. because in the link you mentioned it is written that `/` executes the command that is stored in the sql buffer.

Comment: @viveksinghggits - the first `create type ...` is *in* the command buffer, and the first `/` executes that buffer. Then the second `create type ...` replaces the command buffer contents, and the second `/` executes that second buffer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use single sql statement, end it either with `;` or `/`, NOT BOTH! You can use

```
COMMIT;
```

or

```
COMMIT
/
```

both examples does the same work.

According to your example:

```
COMMIT;
/
```

`COMMIT` is single SQL statement. It is executed because of semicolon(;) at the end of line. SQLPlus remembers last SQL statement. Slash (/) character runs last SQL statement. So in your case is commit executed twice.

Other case is PLSQL block - semicolon (;) does not end the whole block as a statement. It ends only one specific line of code.

For example:

```
BEGIN
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

The code is executed once. SQLPlus identifies code as PLSQL block and does not interpret semicolon as end of statement. You MUST use BOTH semicolon AND slash at the end of block when you want to run it;

Comment: I changed the script's last line to 
`COMMIT
/`
still having Warning: Type created with compilation errors. but thanks for your response